# Fail build if annotation is present with ProGuard

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, release

I would like to **make the build fail if I left debugging code** in the app.
Is it possible to do this via ProGuard? If so, how?

This is what I have currently:

```
/** Annotate methods that shouldn't be used in production. */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS) // TODO which one?
@Target({CONSTRUCTOR, METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface DebugHelper {
}

class Utils {
    /**
     * Dig up object's internals (with reflection if need be)
     * and convert them to string. Useful for View/Fragment/Bundle/etc.
     */
    @DebugHelper
    public static String toString(Object value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Let's say I have accidentally left a `Utils.toString(veryBigObject)` in the code somewhere. I'm looking for a way to make this fail the build (or output a Note/Warning line). Note that there are many classes and methods annotated like this so listing them one-by-one is not a solution.

---

Alternatively **if the above is not possible, I would be just as happy if ProGuard can get rid of those calls** (to speed up released app) **and all the methods/classes annotated with `@DebugHelper`** (to keep the size down).

I've tried:

```
-assumenosideeffects class ** {
    @net.twisterrob.java.annotations.DebugHelper <methods>;
}
```

but it gives me

> Note: the configuration specifies that none of the methods of class '**' have any side effects
>   Note: there were 1 '-assumenosideeffects' options that try to match all methods with wildcards. This will likely cause problems with methods like `wait()' and 'notify()'. You should specify the methods more precisely. (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#nosideeffects)

even though the annotation is pretty specific.

Answer (score 0):

The message is harmless in your case as the respective code does not take into account if an annotation filter has been specified.